# Phabricator Arcanist - Unable to install signal handler, pcntl_signal()

Tags: php, phabricator, arcanist, libphutil

I have a script that is meant to send a comment on a differential revision and is meant to update harbour master on whether the CI build was successful. Lately I've been receiving the following error:

> ```
> PCNTL [49m[m Unable to install signal handler, pcntl_signal() unavailable. Continuing without signal handling.
> [2022-11-10 11:34:30] EXCEPTION: (Exception) Failed to s
> ```

I've tried PHP version 8.1 and 5.6 no luck.
Does anyone know a solution? Much appriated.

Full log:

> ```
> [Pipeline] sh
> echo '{"transactions":[{"type":"comment","value":"failed: http://jenkins.lab.local:8080/job/Lemington_build/685/"}],"objectIdentifier":"D43951"}'
> arc --trace --conduit-token <secret_token> --conduit-uri http://phabricator.lab.local/ call-conduit differential.revision.edit
> [1m[45m ARGV [49m[m "C:/Program Files/Arcanist/arcanist/bin/arc" --trace --conduit-token <secret_token> --conduit-uri http://phabricator.lab.local/ call-conduit differential.revision.edit
> [1m[45m PCNTL [49m[m Unable to install signal handler, pcntl_signal() unavailable. Continuing without signal handling.
> [2022-11-10 11:34:30] EXCEPTION: (Exception) Failed to set socket nonblocking! at [<arcanist>\src\channel\PhutilSocketChannel.php:51]
> arcanist(head=master, ref.master=85c953ebe4a6)
>   #0 PhutilSocketChannel::__construct(resource) called at [<arcanist>\src\workflow\ArcanistWorkflow.php:2414]
>   #1 ArcanistWorkflow::readStdin() called at [<arcanist>\src\workflow\ArcanistCallConduitWorkflow.php:46]
>   #2 ArcanistCallConduitWorkflow::runWorkflow(PhutilArgumentParser) called at [<arcanist>\src\workflow\ArcanistWorkflow.php:227]
>   #3 ArcanistWorkflow::executeWorkflow(PhutilArgumentParser) called at [<arcanist>\src\toolset\ArcanistPhutilWorkflow.php:21]
>   #4 ArcanistPhutilWorkflow::execute(PhutilArgumentParser) called at [<arcanist>\src\parser\argument\PhutilArgumentParser.php:492]
>   #5 PhutilArgumentParser::parseWorkflowsFull(array) called at [<arcanist>\src\runtime\ArcanistRuntime.php:171]
>   #6 ArcanistRuntime::executeCore(array) called at [<arcanist>\src\runtime\ArcanistRuntime.php:37]
>   #7 ArcanistRuntime::execute(array) called at [<arcanist>\support\init\init-arcanist.php:6]
>   #8 require_once(string) called at [<arcanist>\bin\arc:10]
> ```

I've tried PHP version 8.1 and 5.6 no luck.
Also tried the arc upgrade command but I'm on latest version

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because your local version of PHP must not be compiled with pcntl_signal

You can check if it is supported with the following command

```
 php -i | grep pcntl
```

Which should result in

```
pcntl
pcntl support => enabled
```

This link in the PHP Manual is the instructions for installation - https://www.php.net/manual/en/pcntl.installation.php